# Why lldb pretty printers doesn't work for GNU GCC compiled program on MacOS?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, lldb

do someone know, why lldb pretty printers doesn't work for GNU GCC compiled program on MacOS?

I have a simple C++ program, which I compiled using GCC 10.2 (from Homebrew) with the following `CXX_FLAGS`: `--std=c++17 -g -O0`

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << v[0];
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to inspect variable `v`, I get the following result:

```
(vector<int, allocator<int> >) $0 = {
  _Vector_base<int, allocator<int> > = {
    _M_impl = {
      _Vector_base<int, allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl_data = {
        _M_start = 0x00000001005062a0
        _M_finish = 0x00000001005062ac
        _M_end_of_storage = 0x00000001005062ac
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is no `std::` prefix before `vector`, so there is no pretty printer added for that type (by default it handles `"^(std::__1::)vector<.+>$"`).
AFAIU, by default pretty printers in LLDB are enabled for `libc++`, while GCC uses `libstdc++`.

Do someone know, how to fix this and make pretty printers work for GNU GCC compiled programs in LLDB?

Comment: If it is really true that you have std classes whose typenames aren't wrapped in the std:: namespace, then the built-in formatters won't match.  There is no way to re-add the built-in formatters with new match criteria, so you would have to build your own lldb with the match patterns adjusted.  The question I'd ask here is who is providing std classes outside the std namespace, and can you get them to stop doing that.

Comment: GCC binaries from Homebrew gave me the results above with CXX_FLAGS from the post. It requires to use `std` namespace in code, but for some reason `std` is not presented as prefix during debug process with `lldb`

Comment: Btw, I've just tried to use `-gdwarf-3` option and it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

`-gdwarf-3` option resolved the original problem with `std::` prefixes missing during debug process, so with that flag pretty printers works fine.

P.S. `-gdwarf-4` makes pretty printers work normally too